# Unraveling a match statement with monads

Tags: error-handling, rust

I'm trying to simplify the following code:

```
fn foo(a: i32) -> Option<i32> {
    match bar() {
        None => None,
        Some(strct) => match strct.field {
            None => None,
            Some(field) => Some(a * field),
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I've gotten so far. It works, but I can't figure out how to remove the `unwrap()` call to make it functionally identical to the original version.

```
fn foo(a: i32) -> Option<i32> {
    bar().and_then(|strct| Some(a * strct.field.unwrap()))
}
```

P.S.: How would you recommend getting an intuition about doing this kind of stuff? I routinely run into these problems with Rust and it's always a struggle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you should use map instead of unwrap.

```
fn foo(a: i32) -> Option<i32> {
    bar().and_then(|s| s.field.map(|f| a * f))
}
```

As for developing an intuition, that will take time. Keep reading and writing rust code (and code in other functional languages) and this intuition will come.